# failed to call event from gridview linkbutton

Tags: c#, asp.net

basically i wish to set a session folo by button click, but i failed to do so

**i failed to call abcde function(), don't know what to set,i did try onRowCommand,onDataBound,OnDataBinding**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
```

**my link button on gridview**

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkname" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("movieTitle") %>' Width=500 CommandName="cmdLink">
```

**in order to find link button control i did try DataGridItemEventArgs, but it didnt work as well**

```
 protected void abcde(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
  if (e.CommandName == "cmdLink")
        {

             string path = //some path;

            Session["path"] = path;

((LinkButton)e.Item.FindControl("lnkname")).PostBackUrl = "~/somewhere/ + Session["path"].ToString()";

        }
    }
```

**y i do so is because my next page function is depend on the session**

Comment: @ravi can u give basic example for me as references ?i spent my whole morning failed to do so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I'm not entirely sure what you mean, however in case you're asking how to manipulate controls within the grid on databinding, it goes like this:

```
    protected void grdvResults_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.DataItem != null)
        {
           ((LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("lnkname")).PostBackUrl = "~/somewhere/" + Session["path"].ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Item this keyword missing references

Comment: and this is the current problems i facing = =

Comment: hi, can i make it like display the result on click?becoz the result now is straight redirect to video pages~

Answer (score 1):

i use gridview `RowCommand`
the aspx code snippet

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:LinkButton ID="btnLink" runat="server" CommandName="btnLinkClick" 
                 CommandArgument='<%# Bind("roll") %>'  Text="Find Name"></asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

the code behind snippet

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "btnLinkClick")
        {
            string path = //some path;
            Session["path"] = path;

            var button = e.CommandSource as LinkButton;
            button.PostBackUrl = path;
        }
    }
```

here an interesting thing is if u set a postbackurl then second time you didn't get to server side it goes to your given url

if you simply want to set url, it is quite easy you can make a property `url` then bind it through `button.PostBackUrl`. also if u need some value from client side then set `eventagument`

Comment: first error for session, cannot convert object to string; after i removed session, they cannot recognize var button =(

Comment: if you set `string path="~/somelocation"` and `Session["path"]= path` then `button.PostBackUrl = path` here where you get error ? ( to get value from session you have to cast the value suppose `Session["path"].ToString()` )

Answer (score 0):

you need to set `CommandArgument` in likbutton declaration, so that you can use it for binding. [GridViewRowcommandEvents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand.aspx)

```
protected void abcde(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
      if (e.CommandName == "cmdLink")
        {
        string path = //some path;
        Session["path"] = path;
        LinkButton objButton = (LinkButton)e.Item.FindControl("lnkname"); //this is you are missing 
        objButton.PostBackUrl = "~/somewhere/" + Session["path"].ToString()";
        }
    }
```